# MySQL trying to apply UTF-8 encoding when trying to insert bytes to BLOB field

Tags: mysql, utf-8, blob

I'm using MySQL 8.0.4 ([rc4](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/8.0.html)) I need MySQL 8 because it's the only version of MySQL that supports CTEs.

My database is created thus:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS TestDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
USE TestDB;
SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (
 (...)
 Body LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
 (...)
);
```

When I try to insert raw byte data to this description field, I receive this error:

`Error 1366: Incorrect string value: '\x8B\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00...' for column 'Body' at row 1`.

This is the insert statement I'm using.

```
REPLACE INTO MyTable
SELECT Candidate.* FROM
(SELECT :Id AS Id,
    (...)
    :Body AS Body,
    (...)
    ) AS Candidate
LEFT JOIN MyTable ON Candidate.Id = MyTable.Id
WHERE (
(...)
);
```

How could there be an incorrect string value for BLOB? Doesn't BLOB mean I can insert quite literally anything?

Comment: can u post sample insert statement?

Comment: Just added the insert statement I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

What's the `:` stuff?  Why have the nested query?  May we see actual SQL?  What language are you using?  It sounds like the "binding" tried to apply character set rules, when it should not.  May we see the code that did the substitution of the `:` stuff?

`BLOBs` have not character set.  As long as you can get the bytes past the parser, there should be no problem.

However, I find this to be a better way to do it...

In the app language, generate a hex string, then use that in

```
 INSERT INTO ... VALUES (..., UNHEX(the-hex-string), ...)
```